# How to use "DoParallel" for this LOOP which took me 12h+ to run

Tags: r, arrays, forecasting, doparallel, inventory-management

I am currently working on this code. Everything is fine, except...the code needs 12 hours to finish.

I really do want to change this code to use Doparallel, but I just failed over and over again. I have to use Foreach but it seems it cannot improve the efficiency... I don't know how  to design a "parallel" for this array as I need this array for further analysis...

Can anybody help me?

```
Data <- read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/200144.csv")

ourModels <- list("forecast(naive(data),h=h)","forecast(ets(data,model='ANN'),h=h,level=95)", "forecast(ets(data,model='AAN', damped=FALSE),h=h,level=95)"
                  ,"forecast(ets(data,model='MAM', damped=FALSE),h=h,level=95)","forecast(ets(data,model='AAN', damped=TRUE),h=h,level=95)"
                  ,"forecast(ets(data,ic='aicc'),h=h,level=95)","mapa(data,fh=h,conf.lvl=0.95)","forecast(auto.ssarima(data,ic='AICc'),h=h,level=95)")

ourHorizon <- 2 #1,2,6
ourOrigins <- 144-36-ourHorizon + 1 # x rolling origins

ourForecasts <- array (NA,c(ourHorizon,ourOrigins,length(ourModels),ncol(Data)))#max origin, max horizon, how many time series.
ourHoldoutValues <- array (NA,c(ourHorizon,ourOrigins,ncol(Data)))#max origin, max horizon, how many time series.
EMTable<-array (NA,c(ncol(Data),length(ourModels),3))#3 metrics
RMSETABLE<-array (NA,c(1,ourOrigins,length(ourModels),ncol(Data)))

#collect forecasting results and Standard deviation of past forecasting errors
foreach(a = 1:ncol(Data))%do% {# a is the No. of time series
  foreach(b = 1:8)%do%{# b is the No. of the models
    ourData <- as.data.frame(Data [,a])
    #ourData <- na.omit(ourData)
    ourData <- ts(ourData,frequency=12) #monthly data

    #Change Models here:
    ourCall <- ourModels[[b]]
    if (b==7){#MAPA
      ourValue <- c("outfor","MSE")
    } else if (b==8){#SARIMA
      ourValue <- c("mean","model$lossValue")
    } else if (b==1){
      ourValue <- c("mean","model$sigma2")}#?????
    else
      ourValue <- c("mean","model$mse")

    ourROReturn <- ro(ourData, h=ourHorizon, origins=ourOrigins, call=ourCall, parallel = TRUE,
                      value=ourValue,  ci=FALSE, co=TRUE)

    if (b==7){#MAPA is special
      ourForecasts[,,b,a] <- ourROReturn$outfor
      ourHoldoutValues[,,a] <- ourROReturn$holdout
      #measure forecasting performances here #MPE
      EMTable[a,b,1]<-mean(apply(((ourROReturn$holdout - ourROReturn$outfor) / ourROReturn$holdout),1,mean,na.rm=TRUE))#MPE 
      RMSETABLE[,,b,a]<-(ourROReturn$MSE)^0.5

    } else{#use ourreturn$model can get their INSAMPLE MSE
      ourForecasts[,,b,a] <- ourROReturn$mean
      ourHoldoutValues[,,a] <- ourROReturn$holdout

      EMTable[a,b,1]<-mean(apply(((ourROReturn$holdout - ourROReturn$mean) / ourROReturn$holdout),1,mean,na.rm=TRUE))#MPE 
      RMSETABLE[,,b,a]<-(ourROReturn$model)^0.5}


  }
  print(a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. All you need to do is parallel execution as follows

```
# load libraries
library(parallel)
library(doParalle)

# create parallel cluster
cl <- makeCluster(9,timeout=120)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
getDoParWorkers()

## Your parallel for loop

#collect forecasting results and Standard deviation of past forecasting errors
foreach(a = 1:ncol(Data), .packages=c(any packages you need inside for loop)) %dopar% {
 ....
 ....
 ....
 ....
}
```

If you want to further improve the execution time, make the second foreach loop `foreach(b = 1:8)%do%{` as a function and use `apply` function.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but how can I know the process of the loop?

Comment: And how to write that in Function? I am very sorry to bother you but I have no idea how to write this. (I know python but not good at r and this code will be needed for dissertation..so ...)

Comment: Here is a good tutorial for it. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family